# Is it acceptable to have a GFCI on a circuit that does not have a circuit breaker?

Tags: gfci

I bought an existing home 2 years ago. It has 4 GFCI's on outdoor walls. 3 of the GFCI are on circuits controlled by circuit breakers in an electrical sub-panel panel. The fourth GFCI does not appear to be on any of the lines with circuit breakers. However, opening the two 50-amp breakers that feed the sub-panel shuts off the fourth GFCI. The fourth GFCI operates alone. There is no line connected to the load side of the fourth GFCI. Is this acceptable?

Comment: So, just to be clear... you have a 15 or 20 amp gfci receptacle on a 50 amp breaker? If so, that's a no-no on all kinds of levels.

Comment: Are you kidding?  That's a "go to the main panel, turn off the subpanel, go to the subpanel, pop the front off so you can see the wires (warning: assume to be hot), take clear, well-lit pix (that's the trick lol) and post them here" ASAP.  Don't let that go on **one more minute**, that is a super dangerous situation.